# Split string in latest occurrence of substring

Tags: java, string, substring

I need help to split string when substring is found, only on latest occurrence

```
 Substring to search(example):123 
 String: 123hello123boy123guy123girl 
 Res: 123hello123boy123guy (result on split[0])

 Ex: hello123boy
 Res:hello
```

I'm trying with this function, but this split only on first occource.

```
public static String[] getSplitArray(String toSplitString, String spltiChar) {
    return toSplitString.split("(?<=" + spltiChar + ")");
    }
```

Comment: substring is always inside, but it maybe occourr 1-n times

Comment: What if it ends with with the substring 123?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvement on [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent)'s answer: this will actually give you a split array rather than a single-element array with the first part of your `String`:

```
String[] text = {
        "123hello123boy123guy123girl", // 123hello123boy123guy 
        "hello123boy"// hello
};
for (String s: text) {
    System.out.println(
        Arrays.toString(
            s.split("123(?=((?!123).)*?$)")
        )
    );
}
```

**Output**

```
[123hello123boy123guy, girl]
[hello, boy]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in single `split()`, this should work:

```
string.split("123((?!123).)*?$")
```

E.g.:

```
String s = "foo123bar123hhh123tillHere123Bang";
System.out.println(s.split("123((?!123).)*?$")[0]);
```

Outputs:

```
foo123bar123hhh123tillHere
```

Another approach would be, just `split("123")` then `join` the elements you required by `123` as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for that, you can simply use [`String#lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-):

```
-> String s = "123hello123boy123guy123girl"

-> s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("123"));
|  Expression value is: "123hello123boy123guy"

-> s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("123"));
|  Expression value is: "123girl"
```

Comment: I think string.substring() should be used with caution if java version < 1.7 But this answer is also a good way to go.